# Oven setting for pizza

Tags: oven, pizza

Which Oven setting should I use for making pizza.

[image]

Comment: I've never seen an oven dial with markings like this. Can you share what the different settings mean?

Comment: It makes a whole lot more sense with the image rotated.

Comment: I mean option should i choose from this for making the pizza

Comment: Is that a combined microwave-oven device? The two icons on the nine and eleven position could indicate mcrowave?

Comment: @elbrant I think I can “read” at least some of them. Starting at the top, clockwise you have off - convection defrost - conventional top/bottom heat - convection - convection + bottom heat - (probably) grill/broil - (probably) microwave - (probably) microwave + convection.

Comment: Which style of pizza?

Comment: What's the brand of the oven ? Is there a logo anywhere ? We might be able to find a manufacturer's manual

Comment: 420°F for all pizza. Cook until done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the one at five o'clock. It should be the normal baking mode for most recipes anyway.

The way I read the markings is:

- 12 o'clock, a zero: Turned off.
- 1 o'clock, a lightbulb: Light on, but no heating. Alternatively, it could be a preheat function.
- 3 o'clock, a dripping fan: looks like some kind of defrost setting, in which the fan is on, but the heat source is not indicated.
- 4 o'clock, two horizontal bars: Heat from above and below.
- 5 o'clock, two horizontal bars: Heat from above and below, with fan assist.
- 7 o'clock, a horizontal bar on the bottom and a fan: Heat from below with fan assist.
- 8 o'clock, three shark teeth: Looks like some top-only mode, probably a broiling/rotisserie mode.

I don't have good ideas about the 10 and 11 o'clock modes, wavy lines without and with a fan - if Stephie is right in the comments and this is a combi oven, these are probably microwave modes. Else, it must be something producer specific.

For most food, including pizza, the upper+lower heat with fan assist will give the best results.

Comment: 10/11 are most likely grill, nothing to do with microwave

Comment: 3 is lightbulb with fan assist (that's a bulb, not a drop). 1 and 3 are useful for proofing dough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking a frozen one out of the box, definitely the "5 o'clock" setting as rumtscho suggested.

However, if you're using a homemade or fresh dough with fresh ingredients, the 4 o'clock (two horizontal lines) without the fan is worth a try, so that you get a static heat. This should prevent your pizza from getting dried out by the fan.